# convergent or divergent $\int_{-4}^{1} \frac{dz}{(z + 3)^3}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, convergence-divergence

## Question

Determine whether convergent or divergent.

$$
\int_{-4}^{1} \frac{dz}{(z + 3)^3}
$$

---

## Thinking

I'm not sure how best to go about this, whether I'm justified in my result. Basically I'm saying that as I can't find the first limit, the integral is divergent.

I'm not sure if I should be, in some way, trying to combine the two limits (and using L'Hopitals), or if as soon as I've established that one doesn't exist the whole thing can be determined to be divergent (I *think* this is correct).

**If of one of the two limits is divergent, can I conclude that the integral is divergent?**

---

## Definition

If $f$ is continuous at all $x$ in the interval $[a, b]$, except maybe at $c$ ,
where $a < c < b$ , and if $\lim_{x \to c} |f(x)| = + \infty$ , then

$$
  \int_{a}^{b} f(x) \mathop{dx} =
  \lim_{t \to c^- }  \int_{a}^{t}  f(x) \mathop{dx}
  + 
  \lim_{s \to c^+ }  \int_{s}^{b}  f(x) \mathop{dx}
$$

if this limit exists, otherwise it is divergent.

---

## Working

The improper integral is

$$
\int \frac{dz}{(z + 3)^3} = - \frac{1}{2(z + 3)^2} + C
$$

There's a discontinuity at $z = -3$ , so splitting the integral up as

\begin{equation*}
  \begin{aligned}
    \int_{-4}^{1} \frac{dz}{(z + 3)^3}
    &    =
    \lim_{a \to -3^-}
    \int_{-4}^{a} \frac{dz}{(z + 3)^3}
    +
    \lim_{b \to -3^+}
    \int_{b}^{1} \frac{dz}{(z + 3)^3}  \\
    &=
    - \frac{1}{2}
    \left(
      \lim_{a \to -3^-}
      \left[
        \frac{1}{(z + 3)^2}
      \right]_{-4}^{a}
      +
      \lim_{b \to -3^+}
      \left[
        \frac{1}{(z + 3)^2}
      \right]_{b}^{1}
    \right)
  \end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

The first limit, $\lim_{a \to -3^-} \left[\frac{1}{(z + 3)^2} \right]_{-4}^{a}$,
is found as

\begin{equation*}
  \begin{aligned}
    \lim_{a \to -3^-} \left[\frac{1}{(z + 3)^2} \right]_{-4}^{a} &=
    \lim_{a \to -3^-} \left[\frac{1}{(a + 3)^2} - \frac{1}{(-1)^2}  \right] \\
    &= \lim_{a \to -3^-} \left[\frac{1}{(a + 3)^2} - 1   \right] \\
    &= \lim_{a \to -3^-} \left[\frac{1 - (a + 3)^2}{(a + 3)^2}   \right] \\
  \end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

---

Comment: The last limit is of the form $1/0$, so it doesn't converge.

Comment: The integrand function is not locally integrable at $[-4,1] $.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt yes, but what I wasn't confident with was saying at this stage that the integral was certainly divergent. I was wondering if there was perhaps a combination of the two limits that would result in a convergent integral, even though one of them was divergent?

Comment: It's a matter of definition. But in this specific case both sides diverge so it does not matter.

Comment: @Salahamam_Fatima I'm not sure what you're saying, I see that I can't integrate directly over [-4, 1], but I can by taking limits (?). Or at least, this is sometimes valid (here I don't think so, though I wasn't too confident with my reasoning)

Comment: @Dror yes - my question was about whether or not my approach was valid, and if I was able to state that the integral was divergent if only one of the limits was.

Comment: If only one then I think so.

Comment: @Dror this was my thinking... However, recently doing L'Hopitals has made me a bit skeptical I guess, so I wasn't sure if I could say for sure that just because one of the limits was divergent the sum of them would be. For if I have the form $$(+ \infty) - (+ \infty)$$ , this is an indeterminate form which L'Hopitals can be applied to (isn't it?), in which case I've perhaps concluded the integral is divergent too soon. But I'm not sure about this - hence the question. Thanks

Comment: There is no such form. There are techniques to resolve some examples like this, because of their utility. Don't quite remember though. :)

Comment: @Dror it seems that there is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indeterminate_form

Comment: Alright. confusing name when I think of it.

Comment: According to your definition the integral is certainly divergent.

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking, this integral is divergent because the integral of the absolute value of the integrand diverges:
$$
\int_{-4}^1\frac1{|x+3|^3}\,\mathrm{d}x=\infty
$$
However, in the [Cauchy Principal Value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value) sense, this integral converges:
$$
\begin{align}
\operatorname{PV}\int_{-4}^1\frac1{(x+3)^3}\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\lim_{\epsilon\to0^+}\left[\int_{-4}^{-3-\epsilon}\frac1{(x+3)^3}\,\mathrm{d}x+\int_{-3+\epsilon}^1\frac1{(x+3)^3}\,\mathrm{d}x\right]\\
&=\lim_{\epsilon\to0^+}\left[\int_{-1}^{-\epsilon}\frac1{x^3}\,\mathrm{d}x+\int_{\epsilon}^4\frac1{x^3}\,\mathrm{d}x\right]\\
&=\lim_{\epsilon\to0^+}\left[\int_{-1}^{-\epsilon}\frac1{x^3}\,\mathrm{d}x+\int_{\epsilon}^1\frac1{x^3}\,\mathrm{d}x+\int_1^4\frac1{x^3}\,\mathrm{d}x\right]\\
&=\int_1^4\frac1{x^3}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=-\frac12\left[\frac1{4^2}-\frac1{1^2}\right]\\
&=\frac{15}{32}
\end{align}
$$
The approach in the question diverges because the integral is not strictly convergent. We need to keep the two halves together, and omit an interval symmetric about the singularity, in order to compute the Principal Value.

Comment: Your first sentence: It shouldn't be "strictly speaking", it should be "in the Lebesgue sense" For example $\int_0^\infty (\sin x)/x\, dx$ is viewed as a convergent improper integral, although it's not integrable in the Lebesgue sense.

Comment: @zhw.: i don't believe this is integrable in any sense other than the Principal Value sense, whether Lebesgue, Riemann, or probably any since the singularity is degree three. Principal Value works because of the oddness of the singularity and the absence of a second order component. Dividing this function by $\cosh(x)$ would render it non-integrable even in the principal value sense since it would add a second order component to the singularity.